# Sort NSArray Swift Error: could not find an overload for 'sort' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn the basics of Swift, currently trying to create a list of random numbers and sorting them.

```
var myNSArray = [1,2,3,4]
sort(myNSArray,>) //this works  =  [4,3,2,1]

var myArray: NSMutableArray = []
for i in 0..20 {
    myArray.addObject(Int(rand())%100)
}

var myNew: NSArray = myArray.mutableCopy() as NSArray
var mySorted = sort(myNew,>) //This give an error
```

This is the error:

```
...error: could not find an overload for 'sort' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

---

EDIT:
I was able to rewrite this code using `Array` as follows:

```
var myArray: Int[] = []
for i in 0..20 {
    myArray.append(Int(rand())%100)
}
myArray = sort(myArray,>)
```

Which is a lot cleaner!

Comment: As little knowledge as I have for swift, it is not objective-c and type system is different too. `sort` takes an array, not NSArray. Suggestion: forget about objective-c now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, `myNSArray` isn't an `NSArray`:

```
var myNSArray = [1,2,3,4]
sort(myNSArray,>) //this works  =  [4,3,2,1]
```

[image]

But in these examples:

```
var myArray: NSMutableArray = []
for i in 0..20 {
    myArray.addObject(Int(rand())%100)
}

var myNew: NSArray = myArray.mutableCopy() as NSArray
var mySorted = sort(myNew,>) //This give an error
```

It is an `NSArray` and an `NSMutableArray` explicitly.  These classes don't declare `sort()`

Comment: So I guess the next question is how do I convery a NSMutableArray to an Array. But that's for me to look into outside of this question, cheers for point this out.

Comment: Yea, I haven't found a quick conversion yet! Good luck.

Comment: @CharlieEgan Please share if you have found a way to convert from NSMutableArray to Array.

Comment: As of yet I haven't, I will if I do though. @Maarten